# Hibernate 4.3.0 XML Mapping Escape Characters Exception

Tags: java, mysql, sql, xml, hibernate

In my `User.hbm.xml` I have:

```
<property name="delete" type="java.lang.String">
      <column name="`delete`" />
</property>
```

I've also tried with `''` and `[]` but all give the same exception:

`org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions`

`ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"delete"`

If I change the column name from `delete` to `deletea` then it works so I know that it's not escaping the column name properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting this property to automatically quote all identifiers:

```
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

Comment: It looks like MySQL Server 5.6 has a problem with the syntax that Hibernate is using. Hibernate puts `"double quotes"` around everything which is not valid syntax according to MySQL Server...

Comment: Did you set `hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`?

Answer (score 0):

Just try changing this

```
<column name="`name`" />
```

to this

```
<column name="name" />
```